# Accessing two linux systems using one serial console port one at a time using splitter

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I have two linux devices with serial console port. I have only one serial port on terminal server and i want to access both these devices one at a time basis. Can i hub/ splitter do the task if i connect both the systems to the hub output and input of hub to the serial console port ?

How I am thinking it can work is if i poweroff one device then serial console will detect the other and vice verca.

Comment: what is *"the hub"*

Comment: hub is like a one to many splitter(e.g. usb hub)

Comment: a serial hub makes no sense, but a serial switch does

Comment: No it does exists , see the link https://www.getuscart.com/sf-cable-db9-male-to-2-female-serial-rs232-splitter-cable-12-inches?gclid=Cj0KCQjwmZejBhC_ARIsAGhCqneG5MoDEaGG9gRYUW5bjYX0o1E0DuL7_BmHkLfVvD7O_PXsdTm0QrwaAsTKEALw_wcB

Comment: it may exist, but it makes no sense - electrically

Comment: It can work if you can access two servers with one terminal server console port by powering off one device and accessing the other and vice verca.

Comment: right, I've never been in a situation where I have a serial connection to two systems but only one is ever powered on at the time - seems niche

Comment: Suppose you have two servers for some testing purpose and during that one went down due to corruption/network down then you can use and just one serial connection to fix issues for two servers.

Answer (score 1):

There have been RS232 "splitters".  They have been called things like "terminal servers" or "terminal concentrators" due to the way they made multiple RS232 ports (often with attached modems or terminals) accessible through a single network cable.
Most of the ones I've seen can present a menu of servers reachable on the network to terminals or modems attached to the RS232 ports.  Or, when connecting through the network to the terminal server/concentrator, present a menu of accessible RS232 ports.  Or a mixture of both.

These can tend to be expensive, and perhaps too costly for accessing the serial consoles of just two servers.  There are "A/B Switches" which have a physical switch that connects the pins on a common RS232 port to the pins on the port marked "A" or else to the port marked "B".  These can be much less costly than the terminal servers with network support, but you have to physically turn the switch from "A" to "B" or vice versa.

I can't tell from your description whether a physical A/B switch will serve your needs, or you need something with more remote control.  But it looks like you need an A/B Switch or a (small) Terminal Server/Concentrator.

Comment: See the link for this splitter https://www.getuscart.com/sf-cable-db9-male-to-2-female-serial-rs232-splitter-cable-12-inches?gclid=Cj0KCQjwmZejBhC_ARIsAGhCqneG5MoDEaGG9gRYUW5bjYX0o1E0DuL7_BmHkLfVvD7O_PXsdTm0QrwaAsTKEALw_wcB , Suppose I have two devices connected to the splitter's one end and the terminal server console cable to the other end of splitter. Can I access both devices with one serial if I want to access them one at a time.

Comment: No it won't work. The splitter cable doesn't provide a way to signal which computer should pay attention to the data the terminal server is transmitting, and which computer should ignore the data.  The splitter also shorts together the transmit pins of the two computers, and the idle voltage from one computer will interfere with the transmitting voltage from the other, corrupting the signal.

Comment: But if one computer if powered on and other powered off then only one will receive the data from terminal server and vice versa, isn't it? If this can't happen then what is the purpose of above splitter?

Comment: If you never have the two machines powered on at the same time, then it might possibly work.  That's a discipline that's hard to maintain over weeks and months, especially if there are other people besides yourself who may be using the two computers, powering them on and off.  The splitter cable you linked to did not say it has null-modem wiring.  Depending on the wiring of your terminal server's connector, this could be a problem.